# OSX: Dynamically binding a dylib with the loading executable

Tags: macos, dylib, dlopen, mach-o, dynamic-binding

I'm loading a dylib from an OSX executable using dlopen. I would like the dylib to resolve it's symbols by binding back with the original executable. Is this possible?

Note that the main executable will always have a known name, i.e. I don't need to dynamically tell the dylib what to bind back to.

To be clear, I have

```
X: OSX executable
D: OSX dylib
```

1. Run X.
2. X calls dlopen (at some point in time) to open D.
3. D has undefined symbols which should be resolved against X.
4. OSX automatically binds undefined symbols in D against X **before static constructors in D are run**.

N.B. The last part about static ctrs is crucial.

I basically want an LC_LOAD_DYLIB load command referencing back to the original binary.

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure I can work around the issue by adding an intermediate dylib E. Then I can do:

1. Run X.
2. X calls dlopen (at some point in time) to open E.
3. E initialises some proxy symbols then calls dlopen to open D.
4. D's undefined symbols resolve against E's proxy symbols.
5. E implements it's proxy symbols (manually) using X.

Bit annoying if that's the only way to do this though.